# Print PDF using c# without acrobat

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am using this code below PdfDocument is from SpirePDF library. It prints but file is chopping off from left and quality is bad. I want to achieve this without using Acrobat.
I am having trouble figuring out how to do this. Can anyone show me where I went wrong

```
 bool returnValue = false;
          PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument( filePath );
          try {
            document.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
            document.PrintDocument.Print();
            returnValue = true;
          } catch( Exception ex ) {
            //throw new Exception( ex.Message );
            returnValue = false;
          }
          return returnValue;
```

Comment: The title contradicts the question but to answer. Yes, people have done this before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SpirePDF library, but one way to print the pdf without the Acrobat would be by using the **[Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/)** library.

If yo need a Ghostscript wrapper for .NET you can take a look at **[Ghostscript.NET](http://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET)** library.

Printing sample via Ghostscript.NET can be found here: **https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/discussions/470946**